# syntax error when taking input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm new to python. Could anyone suggest what goes wrong with this **input** command. I'm running this code in python 3.7.0 from anaconda

```
def annotation_tool(path):
final_results = []
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
if path != '':
    file_text = open(path, "r").read()
    nlp_file_doc = nlp(file_text)
    sentences = list(nlp_file_doc.sents)
    for i in sentences:
        print("--------- Next sentence is %s ---------".format(i))
        print("--------- Possible candidates are %s ---------".format(apply_extraction(row,nlp))
        num_candidates = int(input("Enter number of candidates"))
        pair = []
        for x in range(0, num_candidates):
            candidates = input("--------- Enter candidates e.g. computer, good ---------")
            polarity = input("--------- Enter polarity of above candidates (pos/neg/neu) ---------")
            dict = {candidates: polarity}
            pair.append(dict)
        result = {"sentence": i, "candidates": pair}
        final_results.append(result)
        is_continue = input("--------- Continue with annotation y/n? ---------")
        if is_continue == 'n':
            break
return final_results
```

Here is syntax error:

```
File "test.py", line 128
num_candidates = int(input("Enter number of 
candidates"))
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is from the line above:

```
print("--------- Possible candidates are %s ---------".format(apply_extraction(row,nlp))
```

missing a closing parenthesis on the print statement

```
print("--------- Possible candidates are %s ---------".format(apply_extraction(row,nlp)))
```